# Flutter Pass two different Objects type to a single page

Tags: flutter, object, parameters, navigation

How to pass two different Object type to a single page so I can user either of it ignoring required:

from:

```
onTap: () {
Navigator.push(
context, PageTransition(
alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
type: PageTransitionType.fade,
child: CategoryDetail(
topCategories: categories[i])));
}

OR

Navigator.of(context).push(PageTransition(
alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
type: PageTransitionType.fade,
child: CategoryDetail(category: categories[i])));
```

To:

```
class CategoryDetail extends StatefulWidget {
CategoryDetail({Key? key, required this.topCategories, required this.category})
  : super(key: key);

final Category category;
final TopCategories topCategories;

@override
State<CategoryDetail> createState() => _CategoryDetailState();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create one variable without defining the type

```
final category;
```

and in the widget check if the value of the category if Category or TopCategories using this line

```
 if(category is TopCategories){

  }else if(category is Category){

  }
```

Comment: this seems simple, don't need condtional check.

Comment: yeah but if you want to show different UI based on the type of category you will need this condition

Comment: btw i cannot check the above type

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: the if else statement